# Copy and paste user defined range

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone please help me copy and paste a user defined range. I have the below but for some reason am getting an error when trying to perform the action. I suspect I am missing one tiny change. Thanks.

```
Sheets("Sheets1").Select
Dim lngLastRow2 As Long

lngLastRow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("Sheets2").Range("A3:A" & lngLastRow).Copy _
Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(lngLastRow2)
```

Comment: You need a column reference in your destination range, currently you just have a row.

Answer (score 1):

You do have an error here:

```
Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(lngLastRow2)
```

Which evaluates to `.Range(x)` where x is some `Long`. What `Range` needs is something like `.Range("A20")`.

One solution is to change it to

```
Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A" & lngLastRow2)
```

Or another solution is to use a `Range` variable instead:

```
Dim lastRow As Range
Set lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    .Range("A3:A" & lastRow.Row).Copy Destination:=.Range(lastRow.Address)
End With
```

Comment: Based on what I got from you it only copied over a single column of data. What I am trying to do is determine the last row of data on Sheet 1 (store that), determine the last row on Sheet 2, then copy all data from beginning through the last row on Sheet 2 into Sheet 1 starting at the first blank row. I obviously need all columns that have data on sheet 2 and not just the first column. I have thought about determining the last row of data and then the last column of data as noted below, but it seems I am making this more complicated then it needs to be.